# Permission denied while doing scp from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Hi I a using jenkins execute shell to take checkout from a branch and then scp the code into another server.This is what I have in my execute shell

```
cd /home/ubuntu/develop/mt_cloudplatform
git checkout develop
git pull origin develop
sudo rm -rf node_modules
sudo rm package-lock.json
ls
cd /home/ubuntu
whoami
scp -r -i /home/ubuntu/key/key.pem develop/* ubuntu@ip:develop/
npm install sonarqube-scanner --save-dev
sudo su - root -c 'cd /home/ubuntu/develop/mt_cloudplatform;npm run sonar'
```

When I run this job I get this error

```
scp: develop//mt_cloudplatform/.git/objects/pack/pack-bf58c140f984418335dc6383c1b1262c4842a113.pack: Permission denied
scp: develop//mt_cloudplatform/.git/objects/pack/pack-bf58c140f984418335dc6383c1b1262c4842a113.idx: Permission denied
```

How Do I ignore these files while doing scp or give them the required permissions?

Comment: The key used may not have access to the develop/ path, try with some other path

Comment: I think the problem is with .git files because there are other folders in that directory too.